# Is it posible to recommend somebody to do something

Tags: infinitives

Among the patterns for “recommend” are:
you can recommend somebody/something [for something]
You can recommend somebody/something [as something]
But I am not sure if I can recommend somebody [to do something].  Someone who is good at work.
Are the following sentences, awkward?
•   Peter recommended his son to fill a vacant job position at his work.
•   My best friend recommended me to be the shift manager in the sales department.

Comment: I understand your sentences fine, and they feel correct, but there's something off about them that I can't quite place. "*... recommend someone **for** some job*" is the natural way.

Comment: Recommend someone to do something implies **You advised him/her to do that thing**

Comment: Rewriting these sentences in a natural way following the pattern recommend someone for something: 
• Peter recommended his son for a vacant position at his work. 
• My best friend recommended me for shift manager in the sales department.

Answer (score 0):

"I recommend you do that" is a polite way of giving someone an order or strongly urging them to do something. "I recommend you turn that malfunctioning laptop off immediately" means that you really should turn it off or something bad is going to happen. It's more forceful than recommending a movie or book, or recommending someone as a potential employee.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recommend) has as sense 4 "to suggest an act or course of action" but dictionaries don't always capture the fine nuances of language use. Their example is "recommend that the matter be dropped", which especially coming from someone in authority would have the status of an order or a strong suggestion, not just "you could drop it if you like".

In other circumstances, "suggest" might be more appropriate, e.g. "My best friend suggested I should be the shift manager..."

"Peter recommended his son to fill a vacant job position at his work." This is a bit different. It could mean that Peter suggested to his son that he should take the job, or that Peter told the manager that his son would be a good employee: the latter is far more likely.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Peter told the manager that his son would be a good employee.